# XNA 3D Model Skin using engine nine

Tags: c#, xna

anyone using engine nine?? from here [Engine Nine](http://nine.codeplex.com)

when i tried to draw my model, there is an exception said that my model doesn't support skinning,, and also if i just tried to draw without skin, there's an error said that 
The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. BlendWeight0 is missing.
What is possibly wrong with my model??
thanks,,